# Function is slow, alternative np.where's format is not user/reader friendly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, numpy

I have a following dataset.

```
ORIGINFACILITYCODE          object
ZIP5                        object
total_edd                  float64
final_edd                  float64
D1                         float64
D2                         float64
D3                         float64
D4                         float64
D5                         float64
D6                         float64
D7                         float64
D8                         float64
D9                         float64
D10                        float64
D11                        float64
D12                        float64
D13                        float64
```

I want to return a specific column value depending on a value in another column
so I have created the following function

```
def edd_cal_func(x,EDD_TYPE):
    if x[EDD_TYPE]==1:
        return pd.Series(x['D1'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==2:
        return pd.Series(x['D2'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==3:
        return pd.Series(x['D3'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==4:
        return pd.Series(x['D4'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==5:
        return pd.Series(x['D5'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==6:
        return pd.Series(x['D6'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==7:
        return pd.Series(x['D7'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==8:
        return pd.Series(x['D8'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==9:
        return pd.Series(x['D9'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==10:
        return pd.Series(x['D10'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==11:
        return pd.Series(x['D11'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==12:
        return pd.Series(x['D12'])
    elif x[EDD_TYPE]==13:
        return pd.Series(x['D13'])
```

```
w25_27_test['fina_EDD_test'] = w25_27_test.apply(lambda row: edd_cal_func(row,'final_edd'),axis=1)
```

However, the running time is 5 minutes. (File include around 1 million rows)

I know that using np.where will work and is faster,

```
w25_27_test['total_edd_test'] = np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==1,
                                        w25_27_test['D1'],
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==2,
                                        w25_27_test['D2'],
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==3,
                                        w25_27_test['D3'],                                        
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==4,
                                        w25_27_test['D4'],                            
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==5,
                                        w25_27_test['D5'],
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==6,
                                        w25_27_test['D6'],                                        
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==7,
                                        w25_27_test['D7'],                                        
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==8,
                                        w25_27_test['D8'],                                        
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==9,
                                        w25_27_test['D9'],                                        
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==10,
                                        w25_27_test['D10'],                                        
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==11,
                                        w25_27_test['D11'],                                        
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==12,
                                        w25_27_test['D12'],                                        
                               np.where(w25_27_test['total_edd']==13,
                                        w25_27_test['D13'],
                                        -1)))))))))))))
```

but, it will not be as reader-friendly/scalable *(EDD_TYPE could be variable)* as the previous function. Is there any better way to revise that. 
(how to wrap np.where as a function?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks really messy and I'm not sure I get your problem.

However, IIUC, use for loops and `np.select`

```
cond = [df['total_edd'] == i for i in range(1, 4)]
choice = [df[f'D{i}'] for i in range(1, 4)]

np.select(cond, choice, -1)
```

Comment: It works for my case. However, I did not really understand. could you please explain a little bit more. The cond/choise are list of list. how this will only return a list. is it broadcast?